# How to get exact height of a letter (Win API)?

Tags: winapi, fonts

How can I get exact height of a letter? I need a height of a given letter, not a height of font (tmHeight). For example, for little "p" the height is less than tmHeight.
Thank you.

Comment: Does [`GetTextExtentPoint32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938(VS.85).aspx) do what you want? You could pass in just the single letter you want as the `lpString` parameter.

Comment: With [`GetTextExtentPoint32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It seems that GetTextExtentPoint32() does not solve the problem - returns the same height for "A", "a" and "p". I was told about function GetGlyphOutline - it looks like what I need...